# Local variable when it copies the original value

Tags: c#, variables

I want to clarify local variables in C#.

When I have a `List<SomeClass> listSomeClass` and I have a local variable:

```
var localVar = listSomeClass[n];
```

Any changes to the local variable will change the variable in `listSomeClass[n]`

Whereas, if I have a second local variable that access the property of this class *through the first local variable.*  This is effectively a copy of the property and any changes to this will not affect the `listSomeClass[n].SomeProperty`.

i.e.:

```
var localProperty = localVar.SomeProperty
```

But, if I access it *through the list*, it does change the property.

I.e.

```
var localProperty = listSomeClass[n].SomeProperty
```

Is this correct for all fields that are not primitives? Or is it because list and dictionaries returns a reference?

Comment: How are you adding to the list?(the code)

Comment: If `SomeProperty` is a reference type any changes will reflect there also.

Comment: Well, your confusion has nothing to do with local variables. You need a tutorial about [Value types VS Reference types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx)

Comment: Keep in mind that when you adding a class you made to a list like `yourList.Add(yourVariable);` will not add a copy of `yourVariable` to the list, it will simply add the address of `yourVariable` to the list, so any change to the initial variable will change the variable in the list, and the other way around.

Comment: Yes - it all depends on type. Value types (primitives, enums, struct) gots copied, reference types (class) contains just reference so if you access it trough local variable or indexer is irelevant. If you have List<int> even setting the localVar won't work.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel So whether a local variable is a copy vs just a pointer to the address is dependent entirely on whether what I am accessing is a value vs reference type.  Is that correct?

Comment: As I stated earlier it is not about local variable, it is about assignment. In .net we don't call it as *pointer to the address* we say `reference`. Rest what you said is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Any changes to the local variable will change the variable in
>   listSomeClass[n]"

Not exactly. Any changes that you do to the object that the local variable is referencing will affect the object that `listSomeClass[n]` item is referencing, because that is the same object.

If you change the local variable, i.e. assign a different reference to it, that won't affect the item `listSomeClass[n]` or the object that it's referencing.

> "if I have a second local variable that access the property of this
>   class through the first local variable. This is effectively a copy of
>   the property and any changes to this will not affect the
>   listSomeClass[n].SomeProperty"

That depends entirely on the type of the property. The value in the second local variable is always a copy of the value in the property, but that doesn't mean that it can't affect the property.

If the property is a value type, then the second local variable is a copy of the value, and changing the local variable has no effect on the property.

If the property is a reference type, the local variable is a copy of the reference, but that means that the local variable and the property are both referencing the same object. The same then applies to the second local variable as the first local variable; changing the object that the variable is referencing will affect the proeperty as it's referencing the same object, but changing the value of the local variable itself doesn't affect the property.